Morita equivalence between category of modules of hyperoctahedral group with the category of modules of direct product of two symmetric groups
I am reading the paper "R. Dipper and G. D. James, Representations of Hecke algebras of type $B_n$, J. Algebra (146) 1992, 454–481".
Theorem 4.18 says that the category of modules of the hyperoctahedral group $W_n$ is Morita equivalent to the category of modules of the direct sum of the tensor product of two symmetric groups $\bigoplus_{i=0}^n S_i \otimes S_{n-i}$. If $V$ is a $\bigoplus_{i=0}^n S_i \otimes S_{n-i}$-module, then $e_{i,n-i}V$ is the corresponding $W_n$-module.
Therefore, I would like to understand the following:
Let $U$ be a $ W_n$ module, then what will be its image in the category of $\bigoplus_{i=0}^n S_i \otimes S_{n-i}$-modules? Its image should be the direct sum of the tensor product of two modules $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{n} A_i \otimes B_i $, where $A_i$ is an $S_i$-module and $B_i$ is an $S_{n-i}$-module. I would like to know the description of $A_i$ and $B_i$ for $i=0,\dotsc, n $.

You used both $d$ and $n$, as far as I could tell with the same meaning.  I changed $d$ to $n$.  I hope that that was all right.

It is easier to go in the reverse direction: a Specht module $^⊗^$ for $\times {−1}$ is sent to the Specht module $^{(,)}$ for $W$. More generally, $\otimes $ is sent to $\operatorname{Ind}^{W}_{×{−}}(\otimes )$. See Prop. 4.11 of Dipper-Mathas "Morita equivalences of Ariki–Koike algebras", Math. Z, 240 (2002), 579-610. The inverse equivalence should be given by suitable restriction functors.

The Specht module of $W_n$ is spanned by all polytabloids [Theorem 2.18, http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AST_1981__87-88__267_0]. In the above-mentioned paper, the Specht module is defined by $z_{\lambda} W_n$. Could you please help me to understand the connection between them.
